# css image flip(4 images in a row)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am new to CSS and I got this beautiful piece of code which works fine for one image but I have 4 images in one row and there are 2 rows.
Problem: All my images are coming one above another..

Here is the link to what I am trying to achieve but it has only one image whereas I want four images next to one another

https://codepen.io/jjhesk/pen/lHdCA

HTML:

```
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="name">David Walsh</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>Mozilla Web Developer, MooTools & jQuery Consultant, MooTools Core Developer, Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    .flip-container:hover .flipper,  
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.front .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00304a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Well, the class front is positioned absolutely, thus, the images will stack one on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The key is setting `.flip-container` to `display: inline-block`. Otherwise a `div` is a block level element, which takes up an entire line.

http://codepen.io/waspnx/pen/wWOJqw

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <ul class="flipper">
    <li class="front"> <span class="name">David Walsh</span></li>
    <li class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <ul class="flipper 2">
    <li class="front"> <span class="name">David Walsh</span></li>
    <li class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <ul class="flipper 2">
    <li class="front"> <span class="name">David Walsh</span></li>
    <li class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <ul class="flipper 2">
    <li class="front"> <span class="name">David Walsh</span></li>
    <li class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>...</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flip-container ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.flip-container ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.front .name {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 117px;
  background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00304a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Generally *explaining* what to change, and why, to achieve desired results, as well as the snippet, makes answers so much better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks scott but How do I change image it comes from class front I want different for all of them. I can do inline background image but is there any better way?

Comment: You can do that by giving a unique id to each div you want a picture in. Then you can add the photos in CSS to each div individually

Comment: Ohkk ya I can do that., And one more issue I am using bootstrap here and when I am reducing the browser size the images overlap each other for sometime and then go down to another row
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">

Comment: I can't be sure. But if the images are overlapping it sounds like an issue with the z-index.

Comment: @Scott Can you help me make image responsive and it should be only 4 images in one row

Comment: @Rahul.Valani The images have a set width and height.. for a responsive layout, you need to use relative sizes as opposed to set values.. or utilize media queries to adjust the set values.

Comment: @Scott My code is working on microsoft edge but doesn't work on mozila it flips my front image backwards

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and the only thing you have to do is give the class flip container a float:left and the align next to each other.

```
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```